# Openshift 4.x can't pull sonatype nexus image with http only

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

Is there a work around for Openshift to access HTTP only image with Sonatype Nexus proxy?  That's what my team provided for POC Openshift.  You can do podman pull with sslverify false, works fine even inside a pod with podman.  But Openshift can't pull it,

```
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pulling image "domain.ca:5000/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:ubi-fips-x86_64-v15.8.2": image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = pinging container registry domain.ca:5000: Get "https://domain.ca:5000/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

It's looking for https://domain.ca:5000/v2/ but in reality it's only "http://domain.ca:5000/v2/".

Answer (score 1):

In OpenShift, Accessing a container registry using HTTPS is the default behavior. You need to add the registry as insecure registry as follows:

```
apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
kind: Image 
metadata:
  annotations:
    release.openshift.io/create-only: "true"
  name: cluster
spec:
  registrySources: 
    insecureRegistries:
    - domain.ca
```

You can edit image.config.openshift.io with following command:

```
$ oc edit image.config.openshift.io/cluster
```

*1: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/openshift_images/image-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Even http works with this solution,
https://computingforgeeks.com/allow-insecure-registries-in-openshift-okd-4-cluster/